# Delete Visio search shapes history

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

Can anyone help me delete the history in the Shapes search panel? I can't bear to see that long list clutter my work space like that.

[image: Screenshot of the Shapes search box]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Regedit.
Look at key

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Visio\Shape Gallery\History

and delete the entries there.